# how to sort list after 3 criterias?

Tags: java, sorting

i have to sort a list after 3 criterias. and i don't know how to do it.

Criterias are:

1. If the object is in another list, than is it before the object which are not in the other list **(most important)**.
2. I have a list with likelihoods, and if the objects likelihood is higher than other object object before it in the list
3. If the int value is lower, than it is for the other object before it (less important)

I only know the compareTo method, but can I sort a list after 3 criterias with compareTo method?

thank you

edit1:

```
compareTo(Object object) {
if(list.contains(object) && list.contains(this) ) {
return this.compareToSecond(object);}
else if( list.contains(object) && !list.contains(this)) {
return -1;}
else{ return 1;}}

compareToSecond(Object object) {
if(this.liklihood > object.liklihood) {
return 1;}
else if(this.liklihood < object.liklihood) {
return -1;}
else {
return 0;
}}
```

is it possible like this?

Answer (score 3):

edit: I have implemented your criterias in the sample `Comparator`

Yes, you can sort a list after as much criterias you want. You only have to implement the interface `Comparable` or a specific `Comparator`. Example code:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<YourClass>() {
                 public int compare(YourClass yc1, YourClass yc2) {
                       // criteria 1
                       if (anotherList.contains(yc1) && !anotherList.contains(yc2)) {
                           return 1;
                       }
                       // criteria 2 and 3(not 100% clear to me)
                       return yc1.getLikelihood() - yc2.getLikelihood();
                  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you sort it based on 1 criterion.
These 3 criteria should be ordered in some way.
Just implement your compareTo/compare method
taking them into account in the proper order.

If two objects are equal based on criterion K,
only then go ahead and check how they relate
based on criterion K+1.

Comment: ok the first time I have to sort the list after the first criteria, if two are the same, then sort it after the second criteria, if tehy still the same, then sort it after the third criteria. so i implement a compare to and if two are the same then i sort in the o path with the second criteria?

Comment: Just implement the compareTo based on my note. Don't sort on 3 passes or something like that. Just concentrate on getting the compareTo right. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know how to do it

You wont know anything untill you try anything by yourself.

What you need are [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)